# Is there a moral to the deontic-logic story?

Tags: ethics, modal-logic, social-contract

In alethic modal logic, it is arguably conventional (or metaphysically thematic) to start with a possibility or a necessity operator. For example, you can start with possibility and get not-possibly (impossible), possibly-not (contingent), and then not-possibly-not (necessary).

Now then you could start with impossibility or contingency, technically, but I think the common point of departure is from necessity. This follows the theme of modal *logic* as logic-via-necessity-of-conclusions, but I always think it would be generally easier to prove something possible than to prove it necessary, so idk...

A symmetrical question can be constructed in deontic logic. Here, though, I feel like it actually should directly be that there is a correct technical order to the deontic operators **and** that this order is actually morally correct, in the sense that arguing from the technically incorrect order is morally incorrect.

Hopefully, it would be that the concept of good or right was the first operator base, and then that we would eventually define evil or wrong. As far as goodness goes, we can have it as obligation and supererogation if we like; note that this would also imply that there is more abstract goodness than abstract evil as such, expressing the formal order of definitional priority in the metaphysical strength of goodness over evil (a subtle but eternal victory, if you will). At least, this is true if suberogation is unintelligible.

Of course, it would take some specification to show that this was relevant to substantive, "real-life" moral riddles, even in the sense of being a genuine state of mind that influences systems of ethical attitudes. However, have you ever read *The Pilgrim's Progress*? This was a popular book that captured the spirit of a major trend in moral-spiritual beliefs. At one point, either the main character or his sidekick says something like, "I never had a good thought until I acknowledged my sin first," and overall Calvinism and its endurance/inheritance are strongly associated with the more retributive/destructive models of church activity. So there are and have been a great many people who at least have claimed to reason from malice first and virtue later, it appears.

Maybe this issue sounds like an abstract echo of "positive thinking" discourse; but instead, could it be true that deontic logic's internal "story" supports a specific set of answers to a substantive set of questions---or is the argument for conceptual order, here, clever but trivial even if relatively true?

EDIT: as an argument, the idea would be something like, "Putting some sets of concepts into a definitional order is a real conceptual activity; the concepts of deontic operators can be so ordered; and in this case the ordering is not a matter of notational convention, but is itself a deontic ordering, that is there is a nonconventional order, and the involved conceptual activity is real activity, i.e. we really can filter the world through the lens of evil (for example), so the real, nonconventional ordering can be correctly or incorrectly performed."

If you think alethic modal logic truly would proceed from a nonconventional assignment, the above argument can be entangled with this counterpart in alethic modality, where a false such ordering might also be dishonest, I suppose.

Comment: [Deontic *logic*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/) does not really deal with good and evil, ethics does. A symmetric question in deontic logic would not be good/evil but obligatory/permissible, and they are dual just as necessity/possibility. Although it is much more common to suggest that obligation and permission operators should be introduced independently rather than related through negation.

Comment: No, good is present as the overarching domain into which the positive operators fall (obligation *and* supererogation, and maybe others, I don't recall how many McNamara details), and anyway my idea was to start with obligation and then get permission and prohibition. We could say that it is prohibited to define prohibition first. Eventually (quickly) the direct modal symmetry is broken, so the definitional ordering has more steps/nodes, but it's still possible to order the operators

Comment: I do not think that permissions (rights) are morally "negative" even though they are dual to obligations. One could probably argue for not starting with prohibitions on pragmatic grounds. It is perhaps "easier" to define a "positive", semantic "positive", not moral one, but then Moses went with prohibitions first. Reading morality into the order of exposition seems like a big stretch.